# `heroku run rake db:seed` fails without error; tables are present but empty in remote db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, heroku-postgres, seed

I've read through many errors people have run into with this command, but my database is failing to seed without any apparent error.

I've deployed a Rails backend to Heroku. The postgres migration succeeded and I can view the tables using `heroku pg:psql`, but after running `heroku run rake db:seed`, they remain empty:

```
myappname::DATABASE=> SELECT * FROM cities;
id | name | country | lat | long | population | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+---------+-----+------+------------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

My folder structure is:

```
root
|- app
  |- db
    |- migrate
      |- [list of migrations].rb
    |- schema.rb
    |- seeds.rb
```

`seeds.rb` is not in `.gitignore`. A sample of the file looks like this:

```
City.destroy_all
Game.destroy_all
Question.destroy_all

c001 = City.create(name: 'Tokyo', country: 'Japan', lat: 35.685, long: 139.7514, population: 35676000)
c002 = City.create(name: 'New York', country: 'United States', lat: 40.6943, long: -73.9249, population: 19354922)
c003 = City.create(name: 'Mexico City', country: 'Mexico', lat: 19.4424, long: -99.131, population: 19028000)
c004 = City.create(name: 'Mumbai', country: 'India', lat: 19.017, long: 72.857, population: 18978000)
```

I'm using `ruby 2.6.1`, `rails 5.2.3`, `pg 1.1.4`.

Would appreciate any suggestions for things to try!

Comment: You're using _safe_ methods in your seed. That means that if something fails to complete, it will not throw an error. Execution will quietly continue. This could be the reason why you're not seeing any output even though it's failing.

Try replacing `destroy_all` with `all.each(&:destroy!)` or `delete_all` and `create` with `create!`.

Then if something fails, at least you'll know about it.

Comment: @SiimLiiser Thanks -- that's very useful info. With fresh eyes this morning, I discovered that a stray word got into the file before a `#comment`, probably while my bluetooth keyboard was failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a typo, but I'll leave it here in case anyone does something similar and gets a no-error fail. The top of my file looked like this:

```
exit# TODO: I had a todo item here...
# TODO: And another
# TODO: There were three comments

City.destroy_all
Game.destroy_all
Question.destroy_all
```

So between running locally and deploying to Heroku, I must have typed that "exit" while I thought my cursor was in the console, and didn't notice in the 260-line file.